# how to change tweeter button image

Tags: tweets

I have implement multi share tweet button on a page. Now I want to change tweeter share button please let me know how can change

```
    <html>
<head>
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="twitter-share-button"
  href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=My%20Tweet%20button%20with%20a%20via%20tag%20via @kb020189"
  data-size="large"
via="kb020189">
Tweet</a>
</body>
</html>
```